# fetching an entry from an INT column as a string?

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

In my MySQL table I have a column `id` which stores some very large integers. I have a query in my Node.js code which fetches records from this table. Recently I've noticed that some of the INTs fetched are wrong. For example, if the `id` in MySQL is `10152687447723705` then Node.js interprets it as `10152687447723704`. I've learned that this is due to floating point arithmetic, as Javascript gets shaky on precision with numbers this big.

So I need a way to convert this number to a string before it reaches Node, that is, in the MySQL query itself.

One other option is to convert the column to VARCHAR, but that would be a bad idea here, as it is a unique index column and there are lots of searches that utilize that.

I've come across some suggestions for using `CONCAT` but haven't been able to understand what the syntax should be in this case, and whether it applies at all.

Comment: Could you not just add a CONVERT(id, CHAR(50)) into your select statement?

Comment: What are these numbers? Are you likely to perform arithmetic operations on them (+-*/)?

Comment: No arithmetic is ever performed on them.

Comment: @major-mann I guess that'll work. But why limit the CHAR to 50? What happens if I just write `id, CHAR`?

Comment: The limit is not important... It was just as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert your column result from an int to a string, use [CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html)

SELECT CONVERT(id,char) as id_str
FROM my_table
WHERE ...

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it to a string in the query

```
SELECT CAST(floatfield AS char) AS converted
```